# Understanding the find() method

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering why arry.find() is working if I write it like this:

```
const tour = tours.find(el => el.id === id);
```

But not if I write the arrow function like that:

```
const tour = tours.find((el) => {el.id === id});
```

Can someone explain this? In both cases I give a function as parameter.

Comment: Because you didn't return when you use `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, you need to return either `true` or `false` in your callback function. So this is how your code should go(in the second case when you use code blocks):

```
const tour = tours.find((el) => {return el.id === id});
```

However, arrow functions have a shorthand, where you do not need to use code blocks if it is a one line statement, and it **automatically returns the result of the statement**, so you don't need to explicitly use `return` to return the result of the conditional statement.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is a shorted line for:

```
const tour = tours.find(el => { return el.id === id });
```

You need to add the `return` in the second case otherwise you return undefined and filter works only with a truethy return.